# Joomla: access article properties from tags module

Tags: php, joomla

So i've got a template, and to design my blog I used the blog.php and blog_items.php in html/ folder in my template's folder. So now I am working on tag-search, that's now not in the com_content, it's in com_tags. So I created a folder com_tags, a tag folder inside it and, since I want the posts to look the same in the tag search and common blog view, I just copied the blog_item.php to my new folder, renaming it to default_item. I have no problem with including that file from default_items.php, but the $this->item seems to be different from the one that was in the com_content component. So, my code, especially when using lines like

`<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_title', $this->item); ?>`

generates a lot of errors, that, for example, $this->item->title is unset. So I've created a simple workaround after an investigation using print_r:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
$this->params=$params;
$this->item->params=$params;
$this->item->title=$this->escape($this->item->core_title);
$this->item->state=$this->escape($this->item->core_state);
$this->item->publish_up=$this->escape($this->item->core_publish_up);
$this->item->publish_down=$this->escape($this->item->core_publish_down);
$this->item->images=$this->escape($this->item->core_images);
$this->item->introtext = $this->item->text;
```

But such a workaround won't let me get, for example, hits of the article, since there is no core_hits variable and this code just looks stupid. How should I do that correctly?

Comment: The place to put these is not in the component folder but in the html folder of your templage.

Comment: There is core_hits.  Your two choices are do what you did or just change the `$this->item` references to the names used in tags. If you want to use the existing JLayout what you did is fine except that you shouldn't be escaping, that's going to end up with a mess of double escaped things. You could make it prettier by using an associative array perhaps and do the assignments in a `foreach`. Make sure you are super careful about the column name matches. You can find the correct one to one matches in the article data in `#__content_types`. In fact you can just decode that json.

Comment: Of cource I used the html folder of my template while working with the com_tags. So there is no way I can access the item's properties just like I did in com_content component?

Comment: Sure just change the code from that in articles to that which is used in the tag layouts.  The model is different because there is no category but look at the default_items layout in the tag view.  You need to add $item->core_body for example and then you will want to do the math-y part to set up rows and columns.  The best model of that is in the tags view.